# Dynatree dnd IE8 - when folder is expanded dragged item disappears and dragging stops

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

When the dragged item is hovering over collapsed node - the node expands but the item disappears and the dragging stops. This is only happening in IE8, and it can bee seen in dynatree example browser http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html - Drag'n'drop 2. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, see here:

http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/issues/detail?id=367